# Error creating Circle object in ionic 3

Tags: angular, google-maps, variables, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using the Google Maps API. Where I have to create a circle around the market created. I perform it with (works correctly)

```
    createCircle(loc: LatLng){

    return  this.map.addCircle(
      {'center': loc,
      'radius': 300,
      'strokeColor' : '#AA00FF',
      'strokeWidth': 5,
      'fillColor' : '#880000'}

    );

}
```

My error appears when I try to create a Circle variable

```
circle:Circle;
```

and I try to change the method by

```
         createCircle(loc: LatLng){

 this.circle =   this.map.addCircle(
      {'center': loc,
      'radius': 300,
      'strokeColor' : '#AA00FF',
      'strokeWidth': 5,
      'fillColor' : '#880000'}

    );

    return this.circle;
}
```

I see this error.

[image]

What is my mistake? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please edit your question with 100% English

Comment: It's difficult to see the rest of what `ContactPage` in your code looks like. You might be better off just instantiating circle like: `circle: createCircle()` instead of what you did. But a better answer can be given if you can provide some sample code that shows the issue in a plunker maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Use

```
circle:Circle;
```

edit method

```
createCircle(loc: LatLng){

    this.map.addCircle({
      'center': loc,
      'radius': this.radius,
      'strokeColor': '#AA00FF',
      'strokeWidth': 5,
      'fillColor': '#880000'
    }).then((circle: Circle) => {
      this.circle = circle;
    })

    return this.circle;
}
```